# Ef core query based on non primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0, db-first

Net core and EF Core DB first approach. I have one table and It has Id which is primary key and one more countryname which is non primary key. I want to query country name and I will not be passing primary key. Below is my implementation.

IBaseRepository.cs

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T>
 {
  async Task<T> GetCountryByNameAsync(string country)
 }
```

BaseRepository.cs

```
public class BaseRepository<T>: IBaseRepository<T>
        where T : class
    {
      private readonly DbContext dbContext;
      private readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;
      public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
            this.dbSet = dbContext?.Set<T>();
        }
       public async Task<T> GetCountryByNameAsync(string country)
        {
            return await this.dbSet.FindAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false); //This will return based on the countryId
            //I want select * from country where countryname = country
        }
    }
```

In the above implementation I can get country by id(primary key) but I want to query based on the countryname. I am trying to figure it out. Can someone guide me how we can accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the first element with the provided country name use the `FirstOrDefault` method. Then Check if the returned value is `null` (Will return null in case `countryName` does not exist).

```
public async Task<T> GetCountryByNameAsync(string country)
{
    var country = await this.dbSet<T>.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Countryname == country); 
    return country;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not able to get C.countryname and it shows options equals, gethashcode, gettype and tostring

Comment: Check the code now I forgot the generic type <T>. One more thing, the generic type T. Should extend a class where the class contain an attribute called `countryName`. Did you got what I mean?

Comment: Because now, nothing says that the generic type `T` we're using contains an attribute called `countryName`

Answer (score 1):

Just use FirstOrDefaultAsync

```
    public async Task<T> GetCountryByNameAsync(string country)
    {
        return await this.dbSet<Country>.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c=>c.Countryname == country).ConfigureAwait(false); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not able to get C.countryname and it shows options equals, gethashcode, gettype and tostring

Comment: Ah normally you should have a DbSet<Country> or something like that on your DbContext... I suspect you have to make a CountryRepository : BaseRepository<Country>